# Contour integral calculation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

There is an integral of a complex function to calculate:
$$ \oint_{|z|=2015}\frac{3i(z^3+z-2)}{\pi(z-3)}e^{-\frac{1}{z}}dz,$$
where the contour is a circle of radius 2015. 
Calculating it manually I get the answer $-116$. But the next command in MATHEMATICA:

```
z = 2015 Exp[I w];
Integrate[(3 I (z^3 + z - 2))/(\[Pi] (z - 3)) Exp[-(1/z)], {w, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

returns $45 i$. I think that MATHEMATICA is wrong. What's the reason of it?

Comment: You should take into account $dz=2015i\exp(iw)\,dw$ . Because of this reason the factor $ 2015i\exp(iw)$ should be included in the integrand.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!